# Why is my spring boot application not being able to fetch CSS and JS files on a random basis?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am getting a very strange error in that sometimes there is no problem and the CSS and JS files are fetched correctly but then all of sudden, it throws error that the mapping can't be found.
I suspect this is some kind of cache problem because closing the application and running a different application and then again running this application resolves that error.
My mapControl.java looks like this:

```
@Controller
public class MapControl {
    @Autowired
    TrafficAndRoutingService trs;
    
    
    
    @GetMapping(value="/")
    public String read(Model model)
    {
        model.addAttribute("pt",new UrlTransformer());
        model.addAttribute("bbox",trs.getBoundingBox());
        return "index";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value="/routing",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String load(@ModelAttribute("pt") UrlTransformer pt, BindingResult errors, Model model)
    {
        
    UrlContainer rp=pt.convert();
    RoutePath res=trs.getPath(rp);
    model.addAttribute("route",res);
    model.addAttribute("bbox",res.getBounds());
    return "index";
    }
    
    @ResponseBody 
    @RequestMapping(value = "/routing",method=RequestMethod.GET,produces="application/json")   
     public RoutePath fetchJSONResponse(@ModelAttribute("pt") UrlTransformer pt, BindingResult errors, Model model)
     {
        
         UrlContainer rp=pt.convert();
         RoutePath res=trs.getPath(rp);
         return res;
     }
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/traffic", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public TrafficData show()
    {
    return trs.getAll();    
    }
    
   
    
 
}
```

My WebConfig.java looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

@Override
public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
  configurer.parameterName("mediaType").
  defaultContentType(MediaType.ALL).
  mediaType("json", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
  }
}
```

And my index.html  (header part) looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
   <head>
      <meta charset='utf-8'>
      <title>N.S</title>
      <!-- Loading all relevant scripts and stylesheets  -->
      <!-- Loading relevant leaflet scripts and stylesheets  -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"
         integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A=="
         crossorigin=""/>
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA==" crossorigin="">  </script>
      <!-- Loading relevant mapbox scripts and stylesheets for geocoding  -->
      <link href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.4.0/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.4.0/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
      <script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-geocoder/v4.7.2/mapbox-gl-geocoder.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-geocoder/v4.7.2/mapbox-gl-geocoder.css" type="text/css">
      <!-- Loading relevant jquery libraries and bootstrap libraries for toggle mode  -->
      <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity = "sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin = "anonymous">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
      <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity = "sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin = "anonymous"></script>
      <script src = "https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity = "sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin = "anonymous"></script>
      <!-- Loading stylesheet for webpage  -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/static/css/styles.css}">
      <!-- Loading scripts for canva5 used in traffic display  -->
      <script th:src="@{static/js/leaflet_canvas_layer.js}"></script>
      <script th:src="@{static/js/leaflet_tileloader_mixin.js}"></script>
      <!-- Loading scripts traffic display (fetch and display) -->
      <script th:src="@{static/js/traffic_disp/traffic_layer.js}"></script>
      <script th:src="@{static/js/traffic_disp/traffic_fetch.js}"></script>
      <!-- Loading script for converting string to title case-->
      <script th:src="@{static/js/text_style/title_case.js}"></script>
   </head>
```

Could anyone help me understand what I could have done wrong to get this error intermittently? And also how to resolve it.

Comment: For starters remove the `@EnableWebMvc` from your `WebConfig` as that interferes with Spring Boot.

Comment: That seems to have worked for the time being. Thanks a lot!